# Advantage of using getJSON over AJAX functions

Tags: ajax, json

I am looking for a typical example where calling the jQuery function getJSON offers a large advantage over using standard AJAX functions (from jQuery or from native JavaScript).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's shorter. Basically .getJSON is just a shortcut for jQuerys

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
  success: callback
});
```

Which now you only do

```
$.getJSON(url, calllback);
```

The advantage over using plain AJAX should be fairly obvious as it is a lot less to type and takes care of all the annoying browser specific differences.

Comment: You are saying that "get JSON from URL and execute this callback" is not readable?

Comment: If you only specify a url and callback, no. If you specify more parameters, then yes - I *did* say *arguably* :-)